# Run javascript after wp_handle_upload_prefilter in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload

I need to run JS code after wp_handle_upload_prefilter hook. I tried wp_enqueue_script and few other methods but nothin works...

```
function checkFile( $file )
{
    // some code
    // Here I want to some JS code
    return $file;
}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'checkFile', 2, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this aspect it's almost not possible to run a javascript code specifically here. You can try to do it with PHP or, you can catch the related event before or after the Ajax request of uploading. If you want to push the boundaries, try to run a Node.Js command with [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) but that would be most probably a bad practice.